# Composing class of several classes in C++ at runtime

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance

For a parser I'm developing I am parsing an event log. In the log, each line is an event, which makes it easy to parse the file line by line. The events that are logged have a string identifier at the start which is constructed like so:

```
X_Y_Z
```

`X` is always is the same, and can be parsed as a class with 8 members, as it has 8 arguments.

`Y` can be 6 different types, all of which have a different amount of parameters which can be interpreted differently depending on what type of `Y` they are. Creating a class for each of these 6 types is trivial; as they are just `string`s, `int`s and `bool`s.

`Z` can be more than 20 different things, all with a different amount of parameters that can be interpreted differently. Creating a class for these 20+ types is also trivial; as they are just `string`s, `int`s and `bool`s.

As such, an event class could be defined as so:

```
template<typename Y, typename Z>
struct Event {
    DateTime timestamp;
    X base;
    Y prefix;
    Z suffix;
}
```

This would allow us to construct any possible combination of events at compile time.

The problem is that the log file is parsed at runtime and I would like to be able to compose these classes at runtime, depending on which I need. Furthermore, I would like to avoid casts where I can.

Important to note is that I need to iterate over these composed events after parsing is done, as a second pass of sorts.

What would be the most elegant way to achieve this?

**Edit**: One solution I have thought of would be to use `std::variant`, and storing the Y and Z as an integer based ID in the event class. It could work, but I am looking for something perhaps more elegant than a `std::variant` with 20 arguments.

Comment: You could dynamically allocate the memory for a class in your main function

Comment: Depends what you need to do differently if your event is a `Y1,Z1` type rather than a `Y6,Z20` type. If the answer is - nothing much, you can probably just store a collection of fields. So, _do_ you need different logic for each of 120 combinations?

Comment: Not for all of the 120 combination, let's say there's about 50 different paths to take.

Comment: Is there a specific need to make this be a template (static polymorphism) as opposed to using inheritance (dynamic polymorphism)?

Comment: No, dynamic polymorphism would be acceptable, too.

Comment: @JesseBrands Then double dispatching can solve the problem.

Comment: If you can write an actual answer with an example of how Double Dispatch would solve this problem, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @JesseBrands Done. I did my best to give you a meaningful example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If polymorphism based solutions are viable, you can use double dispatching techniques to do that.
It follows a minimal, working example to show how it could work:

```
struct X { int i; int j; };

struct Visitor;

struct YBase { virtual void accept(Visitor &) =0; };
struct Y1: YBase { void accept(Visitor &) override; int i; };
struct Y2: YBase { void accept(Visitor &) override; bool b; };

struct ZBase { virtual void accept(Visitor &) = 0; };
struct Z1: ZBase { void accept(Visitor &) override; double d; };
struct Z2: ZBase { void accept(Visitor &) override; char c; };

struct Visitor {
    void visit(Y1 &y1) { y1.i = 0; }
    void visit(Y2 &y2) { y2.b = true; }
    void visit(Z1 &z1) { z1.d = .42; }
    void visit(Z2 &z2) { z2.c = 'c'; }
};

void Y1::accept(Visitor &v) { v.visit(*this); }
void Y2::accept(Visitor &v) { v.visit(*this); }
void Z1::accept(Visitor &v) { v.visit(*this); }
void Z2::accept(Visitor &v) { v.visit(*this); }

struct Event {
    X base;
    YBase *prefix;
    ZBase *suffix;
};

void visit(Event &e) {
    Visitor v;
    e.prefix->accept(v);
    e.suffix->accept(v);
}

int main() {
    Y2 y;
    Z1 z;
    Event e;
    e.prefix = &y;
    e.suffix = &z;
    visit(e);
}
```

For I don't know what's the real problem in details, I made my best to give you a meaningful example. I imagine you can use the visitor class to extract the parameters of interest from your erased `Y*`/`Z*` instances.
Anyway, this can be used as a point from which to start to design your own solution based on double dispatching.